Laravel error with php artisan migrate in mysql
Can you help me with this error? I can't migrate my file in mysql.
I'm running the latest version of laravel when i migrate in the terminal.
When i run:
php artisan migrate

I get the following error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table agricultures1.archives (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table archives add constraint archives_farmers_id_foreign foreign key (farmers_id) references farmers (id) on delete cascade)



Edit your question and share migration file for archives table.

please include both migration files, for archives and farmers tables

I am also new in this laravel field. I had a similar error in the past.It is necessary to pay attention to the definitions you make when migrating. If I'm not mistaken, you should write something like this:
$table->foreign('farmers_id')->references('id')->on('farmers')->onDelete('cascade');

but u have to be sure farmes_id and id columns match and farmers is created before the archives. Also u can try php artisan migrate:rollback and then try again php artisan migrate.
